# Is there a way that I could put a number of data into one element of an array or do I need to create one array per data?

Tags: java

If I have an array for a bank client's transaction number, would I need a different array to store their balance and another for their names, etc.?

Is there a way that I could put all of those data into one element of the array? So that when I call the first element of the array, all the data (that is, the transaction number, balance, and name) would be printed out.

Comment: Yes. It is possible. Can you post your structure of current all arrays ?

Comment: As this not a real bank, hope so, or it would explain why they need so much public money...could you tag your question as homework ?

Answer (score 2):

Put those fields into a class and make an array of objects.

Answer (score 1):

```
private class Transaction {
  public String name;
  public int balance;
  public int number;
  public Foo etc;
}

private Transaction[] transactions = new Transaction[transactionCount];
```

Now you can say, e.g.:

```
int thatGuysBalance = transactions[thatGuysIndex].balance;
```

Or:

```
Transaction t = new Transaction();
t.balance = 1000000;
t.number = 3;
t.name = "That Guy";

transactions[thatGuysIndex] = t;
```

Comment: Why oh why to you make an example using Objects with public fields. That's bad practice.

Comment: Because I'm not writing a book.  Feel free to edit the answer if you don't like it.

Comment: @JB Nizet In such a small example, do you not agree getters/setters cloud understanding? Surely _best practice_ should come after a basic understanding of objects :)?

Answer (score 1):

Look into the use of `java.util.List` and `ArrayList` and `Map`s. They are much easier to use and may have higher performance, depending on your needs.